# Build Gradle: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Tags: git, gradle, build.gradle

I am trying to execute git command in my `build.gradle` file as shown below

```
    println '===============>'
    if (!branch){
        // For local build
        def proc = "git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD".execute()
        proc.in.eachLine {line -> println "===>$line"}
        proc.err.eachLine {line -> println '===>ERROR: ' + line}
        proc.waitFor()
    }
    println '<==============='
```

On execution it gives the below error:

```
===============>
===>ERROR: fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent direc[![enter image description here][1]][1]tories): .git
<===============
```

When I tried to check the files/folders via `ls -a` I can see the `.git` folder

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if that will help you, but I had the same problem.
My case was that my `build.gradle` was taking the wrong directory to execute.

At some of the file, I had the definition of the workingDir, I just had to change it:

```
- workingDir: File = File("."),
+ workingDir: File = projectDir,
```

I could figure the error was related to distributions of JDK to ARM64 architecture. You could also try to fix the error by changing to a distribution of JDK to x86.